# case:27(ESC) doesn't work with microsoft edge

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge

As the title say's, the other cases work in google chrome, firefox, iexplore and opera. Does someone know why this is and what the correct code for edge is so that the case would work and go to another page (that's what #messagebtn does).

Further i want to thank everyone for their time.

```
document.addEventListener("keyup",function(e){
   var key = e.which||e.keyCode;
   switch(key){
      //enter
      case 13:
         document.getElementById("messagebtn").click();
      break;
            //space
      case 32:
         document.getElementById("messagebtn").click();
      break;
            //escape
      case 27:
         document.getElementById("messagebtn").click();
      break;

   }
});
```

Comment: seems to be working fine

Comment: Should your break statements be indented to be in-line with ‘document.getEle...()’?

Comment: I cannot reproduce.

Comment: cancel the default action to stop the event bubbling.

Comment: check with microsoft edge www.gester.nl With all browsers escape goes to next page link but not with edge